# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, but I successfully created instance of this class

Tags: java, classloader, noclassdeffounderror, lwjgl, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to write launcher for one "game" that using LWJGL and I needed to load its classes from other JARs.

So I did the following:

```
// ...

// The files that i must load.
String[] files = new String[] { "lwjgl.jar", "jinput.jar", "lwjgl_util.jar", "game_jar.jar" }; 

// Converting strings to URLs
urls = new URL[files.length];
 for ( int i = 0; i < files.length; i++ )
  urls[i] = new File(directoryWithMyJARsAsFileClass, files[i]).toURI().toURL();

// I'ts needed too
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", directoryWithMyLWJGLNativessAsFileClass.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator);
System.setProperty("net.java.games.input.librarypath", directoryWithMyLWJGLNativessAsFileClass.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator);

// All paths are correct, I tested it.

// Class loading
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())
// Object test = loader.loadClass("org.lwjgl.LWJGLException").newInstance(); // (2)
Object game = loader.loadClass("the.game.package.MainClass").newInstance(); // (1)

// ...
```

But code crashes on (1) with error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at my.own.packacge.MyLauncher.main(MyLauncher.java:##) <- ## pointing to (1)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

And if I'll uncomment (2) then instance of org.lwjgl.LWJGLException will be successfully created and I can do some things with it! Class org.lwjgl.LWJGLException loaded and works, but game can't use that.
My question is "HOW? WHY?".

I also decompiled main class of the game, and saw that org.lwjgl.LWJGLException is first import from other JAR:

```
...
import some.import.Class;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.Sys;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextCapabilities;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;
import other.import.Class;
...
```

I'm newbie with ClassLoaders, so maybe i did stupid mistake? I used URLClassLoader because I have not found other simple way to load classes from JAR. I tested it on other project, it works OK.

Comment: Probably the loaded class isn't available to the parent classloader (the one launching `main`)

Comment: Could be one of two cases ,either the class is not available to parent class loader..or the class is being loaded twice both by parent and child classloader and hence out of ambiguity , runtime gives you classnotfount

Comment: In the decompiled source of the `MainClass`, do you any custom class loaders being used ? Any multithreading code there ?

Comment: @Rekin, @Mukul Goel, can tell me in more detail? Or give me link to article about this problem... Googling second day, absolutely do not understand why that heppening.

@Santosh, no, just one class with `public static void main(String[] args) { ... }`